# Program with scanf %m is not portable

Tags: c, cross-compiling, glibc

I have written a C program and it has been working *correctly* (i.e. doing what it's supposed to do) on my machine. I moved it to a different machine and now it's not working as intended (i.e. it doesn't crash but it's just skipping whole parts of the program). I'm suspecting the usage of scanf's %m since it's non-standard. Note I'm compiling my ptogram with std=c99. I checked the versions of glibc on my machine and the other machine; they are *(Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.13-20ubuntu5) 2.13* and *(GNU libc) 2.14.1* respectively.

Does anyone know if the std or glibc version could be the problem?

Comment: Stack Overflow Rule of Thumb #7: If the OP says "my program is working correctly", the OP's program is full of horrible undefined behaviour, and the OP expects everyone to guess the problem that invariably comes up.

Comment: #1 show some code.  #2 describe how you can tell that it is "just skipping whole parts of the program"

Comment: Are you using gcc to compile on both machines? Is it the same version?

Comment: Are you sure you do not have the glibc the wrong way around?

Comment: Did you rebuild on the other machine?

Answer (score 1):

When running the program you need a libc that is compatible with the functionality you are using. If you are using non-standard extensions, you need to check the documentation for the target platform and make sure it supports the same extension.

The best way to avoid such problems is to avoid using extensions. By sticking to the standard you increase the portability of your program.

Also, compile the program locally on each platform. A lot of the differences between different platforms are handled in the standard `#include` files, which means that even if the code is portable, the binaries often aren't.